# How can I disable the default animation of the QPushButton?

Tags: c++, qt

When I click the Push Button, it shows me the animation of it being clicked, I can't find a method to remove it. The only thing that came close is disabling the button after pressing it, but that doesn't remove the animation entirely. I just want the button to be completely static.

Stylesheets do not work

Comment: The animations of various widgets depend on the operating system. It should be the exact same animation as every other button of every other application. Is the animation somehow different than the operating system standard or is it the same and you want it to be different?

Comment: I want to disable it completely, the animation is the default animation of the QPushbutton. I want it to not move when I click it

Comment: You already said that in the question and you did not answer my question. Do you want a standard button or a non-standard button?

Comment: I want a standard button

Comment: What OS and Qt version is this on? This should not happen. Double-check that the animation is different then on other applications. Maybe make a gif of a standard button and a QPushButton side-by-side.

Comment: The animation is not different, it's the usual animation of pressed QPushButton. I want to disable it.

WIndows 7, Qt Creator 4.8.2 (Community)

Comment: There is no such thing as "the usual animation of a pressed QPushButton". It looks different depending on OS. It is supposed to look and behave like a Windows 7 button. Does it look and behave like a Windows 7 button? Do you want it to look like a Windows 7 button?

Comment: Are you sure it is a good idea to have a button without animation ? Your user may be thinking the button did not work if it is not animated.
If you really want to do so, you can set the 'flat' property to your button to make it looks like a Label

Comment: I did it, it's flat. To indicate that it's pressed I have a label that changes colors when you press the button

Comment: How important is it that the button looks like a Windows 7 button?  You could use Qt Stylesheets to give it a different appearance, which would disable animations by default.

Comment: I used stylesheets:
QPushButton {border: none; color: rgb(255, 255, 255);}
QPushButton:hover{background-color: rgb(100, 100, 100);}
It doesn't disable the animation

Comment: Strange... your stylesheet code appears to disable the clicked animation in my test application.  It maintains the defined color change on hover.

Comment: https://imgur.com/nUwnrRP - Example of my button working

Comment: Ah, I got it. It was a problem with my Windows. Thanks everyone anyway

Comment: Do you mind elaborating on the problem with your Windows instance that you solved?

Comment: I disabled a lot of visual effects in my Windows 7, that, for some reason, caused the button to not behave properly. After turning those visual effects on, the button became static like it is supposed to be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I disabled a lot of visual effects in my Windows 7, that caused the button to show the animation despite the fact that I used a stylesheet. After turning those visual effects on, the button became static.